# Can a Message have multiple senders?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

When I want to check who send a specific email to me with JavaMail.

I can use

```
Message.getFrom()
```

which returns an

```
Message[]
```

In what circumstances can a revived Message have multiple Identities it came from?

Regarding the [API](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Message.html#getFrom%28%29) this makes more sense for outgoing Emails.

So can I really on, that:

```
Address from = message.getFrom()[0];
```

Always gives me back exactly 1 Address which the Message was send from?

**I have now Implemented something like:**

```
Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();

if (fromAddress == null || fromAddress.length > 1) {
    // Don't Process the Email and Notify me
}
```

Comment: The documentation shows that it can return an *empty* array.

Comment: This makes sense if you want to send a Message and haven't set it yet. But every incoming Message should have exactly one Identity it came from. I don't get why an Email/Message ever should have more than one From field...

Comment: Zero and one happen in practice. More than one is a sure sign of spam these days (that was different in the previous millenium) so just make sure your code doesn't crash in that case and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it seems that `Message.getFrom()` can really return multiple addresses.

I had a look at the sources for Apache Geronimo's implementation of the JavaMail API, and it will return multiple addresses if there are multiple `From:` headers, or multiple addresses inside one header.

As to whether this could happen:

As explained by Alex K.'s answer, the standard allows multiple "From" addresses if there is a single "Sender". I don't know whether anyone really sends mails with multiple "From" addresses, but it is standards-compliant.

Another situation which actually happens in practice:

Some spammers apparently send mail with multiple `From:` headers. This is not standards-compliant, but apparently some mail servers still accept the mail. This is apparently done to get past mail filters that filter by the `From:` address. The spammers include multiple addresses in the hope that a simple-minded filter will let the message pass if it finds one header with a "From"-address it likes.

**So in summary:** Yes, you should expect `Message.getFrom()` to return multiple addresses (or none at all). However, you probably don't need to expend a lot of energy for handling that case. Maybe you can even get away with just logging it as an error - that depends on your application.

Answer (score 6):

SMTP's `MAIL FROM` command allows only 1 address however the `From:` header (IMF Format) is not restricted to a single address

> **RFC 5322, 3.6.2.  Originator Fields**:
> The originator fields of a message consist of the from field,   **...**  The from field consists of the field name "From" and a
> comma-  separated list of one or more mailbox specifications.

(This works because the RFC requires a single `sender` header if there are multible `from`s)