# Ruby on Rails GMail for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, struct, gmail

I am currently developing a website that can load an email from GMail. I am using gem [GMail for Ruby](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail). It's working good, but when I want to fetch sender name, it's return struct (I still not sure what is this), but I installed Awesome Print to get more information about this variable.

```
> gmail = Gmail.connect("username@gmail.com", "password")
=> #<Gmail::Client0x1019be400 (username@gmail.com) connected> 
> email = gmail.inbox.find(:unread).last
=> #<Gmail::Message0x104e82560 mailbox=INBOX uid=3194> 
> ap email.from
=> [0] #<Struct:Net::IMAP::Address:0x104ea1140
    host = "gmail.com",
    mailbox = "testing123",
    name = "test",
    route = nil
```

I want to get the "name" value, but I can't get it. How can I get it? I read about struct, but when I do `ap email.from.name` it returns `NoMethodError: undefined method 'name' for #<Array:0x00000104ea1488>`

Could someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: I haven't used Awesome Print but looking at "[0]" in the output, It looks like `email.from` is an `Array`. Try `email.from.last.name`.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh - Thank you! That's working.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh - Pardon me, but why using ".last" is working? I want to understand why it works like that way. Thank you again.

Comment: This `gmail` gem must assume there can be more than 1 sender (from) in an email (i wonder how). So, they return an array of senders in `email.from`. To get name of all of them, you can do `email.from.map(&:name)` OR if you are sure, there will be only 1 sender in your implementation, you can pick either `email.from.first` or `email.from.last`. Both will be same.

Comment: Try reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480430/can-a-message-have-multiple-senders

Comment: @JagdeepSingh - Got it. Thank you!